# Validation in mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am writing validations for user schema entries in mongoose. I want to make any one of two entries (password, googleId) required in the schema, but not both the entries are required. I want to make sure that user have either password or googleId. How this can be done? Following is me Schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        validate: (value)=>
        {
            if(value.includes(this.uname))
            {
                throw new Error("Password must not contain username")
            }
        }
    },
    googleId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [custom validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators) :

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: checkCredentials,
            message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
        },
    },
    googleId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});


function checkCredentials(value) {
   if (!this.password || !this.googleId) {
       return false;
   }
   return true; 
}
```

Or with a `pre` validation middleware

```js
UserSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if (!this.password || !this.googleId) {
        next(new Error('You should provide a google id or a password'));
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: if condition is logically incorrect, it should be like this `if (!this.password && !this.googleId)`

Answer (score 0):

What you could probably do is to add a pre validate check and then either call next or invalidate the document.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    googleId: {
        type: String
    }
});

schema.pre('validate', { document: true }, function(next){
    if (!this.password && !this.googleId)
        this.invalidate('passwordgoogleId'. 'One of the fields required.');
    else
        next();
});
```

I haven't tried it though.

Comment: if (!this.password && !this.googleId) would work || is not correct logically

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose schema provides a `prevalidate` middleware which is used to validate the document and make any necessary modifications to it before the validation occurs.

```js
import mongoose, { ValidationError } from "mongoose";
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    googleId: {
        type: String,
    }
});

// This is a middleware
UserSchema.pre('validate', (next) => {
  if (!this.password && !this.googleId) {
    // if both are not available then throw the error
    const err = new ValidationError(this);
    err.errors.password = new ValidationError.ValidatorError({
      message: 'At least one of password or googleId must be present.',
      path: 'password',
      value: this.password
    });
    next(err);
  }
  else { 
    next();
  }
});
```